# What is the [delta] tag for?

Tags: discussion

While browsing [unpopular tags](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags?page=28&tab=popular), I found that the tag [delta](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta) has no description nor question using it. Some tags without questions are just synonyms, but this one seems to be unused.

Thus, I was wandering what subjects is was meant to. Is it the delta wing (in which case it should be synonym of the [delta-wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-wing) tag) or delta airline, or something else. Given the ambiguity, the description must be updated (or the tag removed) but to do it I must understand what subject the tag was made for.

Comment: <the tag delta has no description nor question using it.> tags with no questions get automatically deleted by the system. as this tag exists, there must be a question using it, and in fact there is: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/77946/1467 don't know why it would not appear to you

Comment: @Federico ho! I didn't see it. For me, when clicking on the tag I have "0 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers ". Thus I should transform the question but I don't know if I must propose a synonym of delta-wing or a bug-report as this question does not appear for me.

Comment: no worries, bugs happen and are not your fault. fell free to both make a bug report and update the question. personally, I would support a synonym request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [delta](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta) tag is currently only used for one question:

- [What are the disadvantages of fitting underwing flaps to a Mirage III/5 fighter jets to lower landing speeds?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/77946/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-fitting-underwing-flaps-to-a-mirage-iii-5-fighter)

This question is clearly about delta wings, which already have a tag [delta-wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-wing). Therefore, I think the question should just be re-tagged accordingly, which will automatically delete the [delta](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta) tag.

I don't think a tag synonym **delta** should be created because of the ambiguity mentioned in your question. **delta-wing** is much more descriptive and will automatically appear as a tag suggestion when typing "delta" in the tag field, which IMHO eliminates the need for a synonym.

Comment: Seems like it. [The original revision](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/revisions/77946/1) was tagged with [delta] and [wingee] (typo).

Comment: I agree, I just re-tagged the question as suggested.